# no accessible initializaers, Swift Singleton

Tags: swift, delegates, singleton

UPDATE

just tried to remove the

```
init(delegate: MPPlayerDelegate) {
self.delegate = delegate
}
```

and do as i was told with

```
var updateLabel: MPPlayerDelegate = MPPlayerSingleton()
```

in UIVIewcontroller.swift

but still a problem. 
    **MPPlayerDelegate does not have a member named delegate**

I'm trying to build a singleton with a delegate so it can update a uilabel with the information it gets from a http stream "Radio"

i'm getting the error

**MPPlayerDelegate cannont be constructed because it has no accessible initializaers**

MPPlayerSingleton.swift

```
 @objc protocol MPPlayerDelegate{
func updateLabel(artist: String, title: String)

}


public class MPPlayerSingleton : NSObject, MPPlayerDelegate {

var delegate: MPPlayerDelegate?

init(delegate: MPPlayerDelegate) {
    self.delegate = delegate


}


let songInfo = NSMutableDictionary()
var moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
var uiView = UIView()

var informationMetaTitle: String!
var informationMetaArtist: String!

class var shared: MPPlayerSingleton {

    struct Static {
        static var instances: MPPlayerSingleton?
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0

    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        Static.instances = MPPlayerSingleton(delegate: MPPlayerDelegate())  // **This is where the error is** 
    }

    return Static.instances!
}



func updateLabel(artist: String, title: String) {

}
```

UIViewController.swift

```
var updateLabel: MPPlayerDelegate = MPPlayerDelegate() // **same error here**
    updateLabel.delegate = self // says there is no delegate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you're getting aren't related to the singleton, they're because you're trying to create an instance of a protocol, which isn't possible. You can declare a property with a protocol as its type, but when creating an instance to assign to that property, you need to use an actual class that conforms to your given protocol.

Your protocol declaration is fine:

```
@objc protocol MPPlayerDelegate {
    func updateLabel(artist: String, title: String)
}
```

In your `MPPlayerSingleton` class, you don't want an initializer with a delegate, since that will need to be set by your client code. Get rid of that and `NSObject`'s empty `init()` will be available, solving most of your problems:

```
public class MPPlayerSingleton : NSObject, MPPlayerDelegate {
    var delegate: MPPlayerDelegate?
    // ...

    // Cleaned-up singleton  
    class var shared: MPPlayerSingleton {
        struct Static {
            static var instance = MPPlayerSingleton()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }
}
```

Now you can set the `delegate` to one of your view controllers, which is what you probably want in this case:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, MPPlayerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        MPPlayerSingleton.shared.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: - MPPlayerDelegate

    func updateLabel(artist: String, title: String) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant:

```
var updateLabel: MPPlayerDelegate = MPPlayerSingleton()
```

Comment: No dice... the error still persist in the singleton file as i wrote and showed.
at the line with **Static.instances**